# why can't I install laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, installation, composer-php, laravel-8

[This appears](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IWvgi.png)
I followed Youtube tutorial to install Laravel but only in this point it gets error. I can't figure out what to do now.

```
  Problem 1
    - laravel/framework[v9.36.4, ..., 9.x-dev] require league/flysystem ^3.8.0 -> satisfiable by league/flysystem[3.8.0, ..., 3.x-dev].
    - laravel/framework[v9.19.0, ..., v9.36.3] require league/flysystem ^3.0.16 -> satisfiable by league/flysystem[3.0.16, ..., 3.x-dev].
    - league/flysystem[3.0.16, ..., 3.x-dev] require league/mime-type-detection ^1.0.0 -> satisfiable by league/mime-type-detection[1.0.0, ..., 1.11.0].
    - league/mime-type-detection[1.0.0, ..., 1.3.0] require php ^7.2 -> your php version (8.1.13) does not satisfy that requirement.
    - league/mime-type-detection[1.4.0, ..., 1.11.0] require ext-fileinfo * -> it is missing from your system. Install or enable PHP's fileinfo extension.
    - Root composer.json requires laravel/framework ^9.19 -> satisfiable by laravel/framework[v9.19.0, ..., 9.x-dev].

To enable extensions, verify that they are enabled in your .ini files:
    - C:\php-8.1.13\php.ini
You can also run `php --ini` in a terminal to see which files are used by PHP in CLI mode.
Alternatively, you can run Composer with `--ignore-platform-req=ext-fileinfo` to temporarily ignore these required extensions.
```

Comment: `ext-fileinfo` is required for Laravel. check your `php.ini` file and enable it.

Comment: "_require ext-fileinfo * -> it is missing from your system. Install or enable PHP's fileinfo extension._" Even with info on how to enable it

Comment: `require php ^7.2 -> your php version (8.1.13) does not satisfy` - also, install laravel 9 instead.